# Using Node.js to retrieve the results count from google

Tags: javascript, node.js

To give the specific details:

I am designing a Discord Bot that uses the [eris library](https://github.com/abalabahaha/eris/) for private use. One requested feature is a googlefight command which needs to do the following:

1. Take user input.
2. Use input to generate a Google search URL.
3. Pull the resulting HTML page and extract from it the text from within `<div class="sd" id="resultStats">`.
4. Output this result as a message.

The currently existing related code is:

```
const Eris = require("eris");
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const app = express();

...

bot.registerCommand("googlefight", (msg, args) => {
    if(args.length === 0) {
        return "Invalid input";
    }
    var arrayLength = args.length;
    var searchURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=";
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        searchURL = searchURL.concat(args[i]);
        if (i + 1 < arrayLength) {
            searchURL = searchURL.concat("%20");
        } else {

        }
    }

    var text;

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        request(searchURL, function(error, response, html){
            if(!error){
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                $(.sd).filter(function(){
                    var data = $(this);
                    text = data.children().first().text();
                })
            }
        })
    })


    return text;
},  {
    description: "Result counter",
    fullDescription: "The bot will return the result count of a google search term.",
    usage: "<text>"
});
```

I am unfamiliar with this type of work.

The part specifically that is broken is this section:

```
...
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        request(searchURL, function(error, response, html){
            if(!error){
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                $(.sd).filter(function(){
                    var data = $(this);
                    text = data.children().first().text();
                })
            }
        })
    })
...
```

Comment: what on your code works. where is the error?

Comment: @RolandStarke Since others might want to know, I added the broken section to the main question as an edit